# Is it possible to maximize a SDL window?

Tags: c, sdl, maximize

I would like to make my program to maximize using the maximizing button left to the cross in my C program but I can't find how to do so. I found that the ShowWindow Function could be of some help but I don't understand it.

If someone could explain it if this is the solution or tell if there is something else or nothing at all, it'd be very nice.

By the way, I'm using SDL if that help.

PS: the maximize button is indeed grayed out.

Comment: Is the maximize button missing right now, or does it just do nothing when clicked?

Comment: Or is it grayed out?

Comment: Yes, specifying SDL helps - every toolkit has their own set of functions for interfacing with individual windows. See [SDL_CreateWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) and the *Remarks* section of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but it seems that the best way to maximise a window is to use the SDL2 because the SDL doesn't seem to allow maximisation, just resizing.

Answer (score 2):

The 'maximize' button is disabled if your window is not resizable.

Pass `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` flag to `SDL_CreateWindow`, and make sure your code can handle window size changing.